# Что будет с 1С после переустановки windows?

Tags: windows, 1с

Недавно устроился в одну компанию, как системный администратор, теперь назрел вопрос: Хочу переустановить Windows на одном компьютере, там стоит 1C (8.3.15.1700), данную версию 1С переделывали под нужды компании (выплаты пенсий, проценты начисления и т.д.), также база данной 1С находится на серверном компьютере. Сам с 1С никогда не работал, теперь возвращаясь к вопросу, я могу со спокойной душой переустановить Windows, если у меня имеется пин-код(резервные) для 1С и лицензия(тоже резервные)? Также что будет с видоизменением 1С в случае переустановки Windows (я хочу просто скачать из интернета нужную версию, активировать 1C и указать путь к базе) будет ли это работать или нужны какие-то дополнительные действия?

Comment: ну если 1с серверная то да, можно

Comment: Перед переустановкой сделайте образ системного раздела на всякий случай, чтобы в случае проблем была возможность вернуть старую винду и старый 1С

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перестановка винды, может встать в серьезную проблему ! Надо детально выяснить следующие вещи:

1. На этой 1С работают локально, или это 1с Сервер к которому юзеры удаленно подключаются
2. Иногда работают по RDP на сервере локально (надо знать об этом заранее)
3. База данных 1С, файловая или SQL
4. Точно выяснить версию платформы 1С (8.3.15.1700) убедиться что используется одна платформа (иногда бывает несколько) Скачать именно ту версию платформы (и сервера) которая используется
5. Для варианта 1с Сервер, посмотреть с какой учеткой запускается служба Агент 1С (записать) понадобится при установке платформы;
6. Зайти в рабочую базу 1С, переписать используемые принтеры (может виснуть если принтер не найден)
7. Если есть кластер 1С, убедиться что стоят базовые настройки/иначе записать
8. Подготовить пин-коды для активации Сервера, Конфигурации_бд, Пользовательские (предварительно сохранить файлы .lic)
9. Сделать бекап - рабочей базы